# Compound expressions and PHP ternary operator

Tags: php

To mimick Javascript, I tried this in PHP:

```
$what == '3' ? ( $tot1 += $sum ; $nLinesProd++ ; )
             : ( $tot2 += $sum ; $nLinesExp++; ) ;
```

I also tried `{}` instead of `()` . Neither will work.

Is there a way to use the ternary operator the same way as I do in Javascript?

Comment: Did you mean `$a = ($b == 1 ? 1 : 0 );` ?

Comment: I mean: including compound expressions after the ? sign, i.e. attaching more than one instruction to each branching part.

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operator are meant for simple and single expression. If you want to write complex and compound statements then use of `if` `else` is promoted.
But any how if you want to perform this step in ternary operation then you have to write the compound statements in functional block and call them in ternary operator.

```
<?php

 $do = ($what=='3') ? prod() : exp();
 function prod() {
    $tot1 += $sum;
    $nLinesProd++ ; 
 }
 function exp() {
    $tot2 += $sum;
    $nLinesExp++; 
 }
```

Comment: This is true, but a simle `if else` would be easier to read here.

Comment: @M A SIDDIQUI — My question was: 'Is there a way to use the ternary operator the same way as I do in Javascript?' including an example.  I did not ask for _another_ solution — which I was able to tell by myself.  I specifically asked wether there exists an equivalent PHP syntax, for the original JS one is remarkably compact and efficient.